# PowerShell and LuaInterface.dll

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, lua

[LuaInterface](http://files.luaforge.net/releases/luainterface/luainterface/1.5.3)

[Here](https://habr.com/ru/post/197262/) is an example on c#

Im newbie. How is properly to call this dll?
I was trying this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("E:\\lua\\LuaInterface.dll") 

$Lua = new-object LuaInterface.Lua # Here IntelliSense see class lua after dot
$lua.DoString("local a=5")         # Here IntelliSense see all methods after dot
```

And this:

```
Add-Type -path "E:\lua\LuaInterface.dll"

[LuaInterface.Lua]::DoString("local a=5")
```

But unsuccessfully. Pls, show me example of "3+2" from LuaInterface.

Methods from class **Lua** PS somehow cant see.
On [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T39En.png) powershell can see methods from **luaDLL** class. But there needed always one more parameter **luastate**.

Comment: "unsuccessfully" - what does that mean? Unexpected results from Lua? Errors thrown? If so, which errors?

Comment: Firstly Methods from class Lua PS somehow cant see. And methods from luaDLL needs luastate as first parameter, but i dont understand where i should take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close, but `::` is only for *static member* access.

I got the following working in a 32-bit console (PowerShell 5.1):

```
# Load LuaInterface
Add-Type -Path path\to\luainterface.dll

# Create Lua instance
$lua = [LuaInterface.Lua]::new()

# Set global variable values
$lua['a'] = 2
$lua['b'] = 3

# return result of `a+b`
$lua.DoString("return a+b")
```

Comment: Mathias R. Jessen, thanks thats works! Tell me pls, how i can run lua_dostring($luaState,"os.execute('notepad.exe')") from LuaDLL class? Why it works only from 32-bit console?